# compilation issue when running theano

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, anaconda, theano

I installed theano on windows 8, 64 bit. I am using anaconda implementation, python 3.4. Trying to install theano, I diligently followed all steps on this link (which helped on another computer with similar configuration):

http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano (English and Korean)

whenever I type 'import theano' on my IDE (pycharm) I get a long error message, but I believe the most meaningful portion is:

```
import theano
>>>>Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1):     

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-    

Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-

64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

Would sincerely appreciate some input
btw, I installed mignw64, msys, and all other dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. the path environment variable was not pointing to the correct mingw-w64 (which is needed to run theano on 64 bit windows) directory.

The environment variable should always point to the bin subdirectory of the mingw-w64 directory, as in:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin
```

Again, the following post is VERY USEFUL to install theano on 64-bit windows (in English and Korean):

http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano

Comment: link doesn't work. pleas, write short description in your answer

Comment: Which environment variable? PATH, Path, path or something else?