# Theano Windows 7 import error

Tags: python-2.7, theano, theano-cuda

Today I tried to install Theano on W7 x64. I guess I installed it but I also made a mistake in somewhere and I don't know where. I actually want to use it with CUDA.

Here is the programs I installed:
Anaconda 4.2.0 x64 (Python 2.7.12),
TDM GCC,
CUDA 8.0
Visual Studio 13
Theano via Git

Here is the *theanorc* file:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[nvcc]
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0
```

Like I said I've no idea where I made a mistake. Here is the output when I write "import theano"

Thanks in advance guys!

```
In [2]: import theano
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3397704bd624> in <module>()
----> 1 import theano

C:\Users\silverstone\Theano\theano\__init__.py in <module>()
     64     object2, utils)
     65
---> 66 from theano.compile import (
     67     SymbolicInput, In,
     68     SymbolicOutput, Out,

C:\Users\silverstone\Theano\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
      8         SpecifyShape, specify_shape, register_specify_shape_c_code)
      9
---> 10 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     11
     12 from theano.compile.mode import *

C:\Users\silverstone\Theano\theano\compile\function_module.py in <module>()
     16
     17 import theano
---> 18 from theano import config, gof
     19 from theano.compat import izip
     20 from theano.gof import graph

ImportError: cannot import name gof
```

ps: one more error -> http://pastebin.com/V59Pm9Qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compilation issue when running theano](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850090/compilation-issue-when-running-theano)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added system variables? If no, try this:

Right click Computer -> properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables

Add a new system variable

Name = THEANO_FLAGS

Value = floatX=float32,device=gpu,nvcc.fastmath=True

Also add Visual Studio's c++ compiler to the path

Add ;pathToYourVSInstallation\VC\bin\

If this wont work, please go there and do it again, from the top:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401271/7349628